# Allow member of group to change password of others members of this group

Tags: permissions, sudo

Situation is very simple: I have group of users:

- mike
- jack
- lilly

three of them belongs to **production** group(GID = 1)

How to give "mike" user policy to change passwords of jack and lilly ( I mean users which belongs to the same groups as mike does)??
It's something with sudoers file connected, but i search a lot in google and didn't find any helpfull advice.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

In /etc/sudoers the item immediately following the equals is the user that the command will be allowed to execute as.

```
mike  ALL=(user group) /usr/bin/passwd
```

Comment: Do you mean:
mike ALL=(production) /usr/bin/passwd?
It's not working

Comment: @mike_pl try with: mike  ALL=production /usr/bin/passwd

Comment: when I type in console:
sudo passwd jack
i get error -  I don't have policy to access usr/bin/passwd